# Weird behaviour of Kafka consumer/mirrormaker at different DCs

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, apache-kafka

I have been setting up **2 clusters of Kafka (0.8.1.1) located across DCs** , one in Asia and another one in Europe. All of them are **running on EC2 m1.xlarge** machines.

My goal is to **replicate** data of a topic from **Asia cluster to Europe cluster** with **“high and stable” speed**.

I ended up with 3 solutions to achieve this goal as following :

(**Let N = number of partitions of a topic in Asia cluster.**)

1) Using the Kafka provided **Mirrormaker** , with **—num.streams = N**.

It runs super slow at the rate of **around 30 Mbps while we expect around 1 Gbps** as we have noticed this rate at Asia cluster when producer producing data to Kafka brokers.

2) I tried creating my own version of **Consumer** using High-level API in Europe to consume data directly from Asia cluster , and ended up with the same rate around **30 to 40 Mbps**

I have designed the consumer this way.

- **1** Consumer Group (**1** kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector)
- **N** threads to handle **N** streams from **1** Consumer Group

3) I tried creating another version of **Consumer** using High-level API , and ended up with around **400 Mbps!** , which is much more higher than 2 mentioned ways

Here is my new design

- **N** Consumer Group (**N** kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector) with the same group ID
- **N** Threads to handle **N** Consumer Group
- **1** Consumer Group handles **1** Stream

Also , **the more number of N (partition)  , the higher speeds I’ve got from the solution 3)** while solution 1) and 2) remains the speed at **30Mbps** irrespective to value of N.

Right now , to reach speed at 400 Mbps for solution 3) , I have to set our N to be ridiculously large at **N = 60** , with each message in a topic in Asia cluster has **average size of 50KB**.

So my real question is , **I don’t see the technical differences between solution 3) and the rest but how the speed of consuming data with solution 3) becomes so hugely different from the rest?**